# Cannot operate on variables of type directoryObject, MS Graph API result

Tags: c#, foreach, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, ienumerator

I am using below code to fetch the Manager details using Graph API.

```
var directoryObject = await graphServiceClient.Users[user.UserPrincipalName].Manager.Request().GetAsync();
```

I am trying to do something like below to access the values :

```
foreach(User user in directoryObject ){
    console.Writeline(user.DisplayName);
}
```

or even below doesn't work:

```
 console.Writeline(directoryObject.DisplayName);
```

But ,i am not able iterate over values .
I have attached screenshot of the debug watch data of directoryObject.

Please help me in iterating over values of directoryObject or print entities in directoryObject by doing something like directoryObject.entityName
i.e directoryObject.DisplayName
[image]

Comment: You have to cast directoryObject to the correct class before you can access the properties

Comment: But, i am not able to understand which class to cast , as i am beginner.

Answer (score 3):

The `directoryObject` apparently already *is* a `User` and not an `IEnumerable<User>` which would otherwise be required for the `foreach` to make sense. A simple typecast should work:

```
((User)directoryObject).DisplayName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Yes,it works. I was using foreach(User user in directoryObject ) thinking its User type but  i am able to print DisplayName now which is enough to proceed now.

Comment: @AllTech You should really understand that `foreach` operates on _collections_, i.e. sets of objects, while your `directoryObject` variable is _one single_ object, not a collection. You cannot use a single object where a collection is expected.

Comment: Yes, actually i couldn't identify directoryObject is a single object.

Comment: @AllTech What you see in the watch window is the _actual_ type, so that's a piece of very helpful information in such a situation.